# Xcode interface builder aspect ratio auto layout all iphones

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, autolayout

I read as much as I can of auto-layout tutorials but I cannot figured out how I can have my `UIView` (`UIWebView` for that specific example) resize to the screen layout of my phone.
My background is an `UIImageView`, proportionally bigger on **iPhone5**, and **iPhone6** and **iPhone6 plus** .
I want to have my `UIWebview` to get the margin keeping the aspect ratio.
I tried several options (I also enabled size classes option - I did not see any difference on the preview...)

Anyone as a clue on that ?

[image: preview xcode]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're not getting any answers here, and I'm not sure I can help, either; but, I'd like to try by offering what I've done with respect to maintaining the aspect ratio of a given view containing a video, no matter whether the iPhone orientation is portrait or landscape.

In my storyboard, I've accounted for occasions in which the aspect ratio is reversed, in that all videos are either 16:9 or 9:16, but which one depends on how the camera was held during recording:

[image]

So, here is a screen shot of an iPhone displaying a 16:9 (wide) video in portrait:

[image]

Here is the same video (wide) in landscape (ignore the overlapping labels; the Core Data section is meant to be hidden or overlapped by the AVPlayer view, so that users can view the video fullscreen by simply rotating the iPhone):

[image]

Here are the opposites, first:

[image]

And, second:

[image]

These run the gamut of possibilities for maintaining aspect ratio, regardless of a portrait or landscape orientation, and regardless of a horizontal or vertical aspect ratio. Therefore, you should be able to derive a solution from it. Hope this helps!